# Firebase Cloud Function redirect does not allow opening of an Instagram URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, instagram

I have a simple Firebase Cloud Function to redirect to a URL. The code is here:

```
export const redirect_url = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var redirect_url = request.query.redirect_url as string;
    functions.logger.info(`Redirect URL = ${redirect_url}`, {structuredData: true});
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
});
```

This works perfectly when I redirect to my website like this (note the actual firebase project domain is hidden):

```
https://us-central1-<PRIVATE>.cloudfunctions.net/redirect_url?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwealdcreative.com
```

But when I try to redirect to an Instagram AR filter it goes to a permissions page on Google's AppEngine.

```
https://us-central1-<PRIVATE>.cloudfunctions.net/redirect_url?https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Far%2F3357317521220189%2F
```

The page states: `An application is requesting permission to access your Google Account`
I guess `Instagram` is not allowing the redirect or I need to tell Firebase to allow the `instagram.com` domain.

Does anyone know what the solution is here?

UPDATE:
The logs tell me that my escaped version of the URL has not passed in parsed and is `undefined`. This is the escaped URL:
`https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Far%2F3357317521220189%2F`
It should unescape to: `https://www.instagram.com/ar/3357317521220189/`
So this is something to do with why this is not being passed through as a query string.

I tested the cloud function with the unescaped URL in the body of the function and not a query param. It worked and opened the Instagram filter page in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your second URL:

```
.../redirect_url?https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Far%2F3357317521220189%2F
```

should be:

```
.../redirect_url?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Far%2F3357317521220189%2F
```

Comment: Boom! Thank you. Stupid error! My own fault for calling the function that same name as the parameter! :-s